# Unmarshalling json arrays as json objects

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have to unmarshal a series of Json objects, but one of the objects contain a json array which is not really structured in a good way.

```
"labels": [
    {
      "key": "owner",
      "value": "harry"
    },
    {
      "key": "group",
      "value": "student"
    }
  ]
```

I am unmarshalling it using this struct -

```
type StudentDetails struct {
Id        string         `json:"id"`
Name      string         `json:"name"`
Labels    []Label   `json:"labels,omitempty"`
}
type Label struct {
Key string `json:"key"`
Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

And I have to access it using x.Labels[0].key == "owner" inside a for loop which is very annoying. 
I want to be able to do x.Labels.Owner == "harry" instead. How do I go about achieving this? The rest of JSON is unmarshalled fine using the default unmarshal function, so I don't think writing custom function will be good option.

Comment: Explain more about why  custom unmarshal is a problem. The best solution is to declare a type for Labels and write a custom [unmarshal method](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler.UnmarshalJSON) for that type.

Comment: @ThunderCat The labels array will be a dynamic one which could change over time, it's like a generic KV pair. If today I write a custom decoder for "owner" key, it may not exist later, or may have many additional keys like "class" or "domain".

Comment: The unmarshal function will transform key value pairs from the JSON to a Go map.  In doing so, the unmarshal function does not need to know what the keys are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the constraints you have here, this is about as close as you will get ([run in playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CDIg8s4ZkVj)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    j := `
        {
            "id": "42",
            "name": "Marvin",
            "labels": [
                {
                    "key": "owner",
                    "value": "harry"
                },
                {
                    "key": "group",
                    "value": "student"
                }
            ]
        }`

    d := StudentDetails{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d.Labels["owner"])
    fmt.Println(d.Labels["group"])
}

type StudentDetails struct {
    Id     string `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Labels Labels `json:"labels"`
}

type Labels map[string]string

func (l *Labels) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    a := []map[string]string{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t := map[string]string{}
    for _, m := range a {
        t[m["key"]] = m["value"]
    }
    *l = t
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Still trying to wrap my brain around the logic behind  the Unmarshal function. What exactly does byte contain here? Is it the labels array or just one json object of that array? What's inside a? Edit: Nevermind, printing inside the unmarshal function explained everything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about to define custom `[]Label` type and add function on it.

For instance

```go
type Labels []Label

func (l Labels) Owner() string {
    if len(l) > 1 {
        return l[0].Value
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Label field is a generic one, I'm not sure of the fact that l[0] will always be owner. It is possible for l[1] to be owner and l[0] to be group. Or maybe neither of these two.